# How to parse json data in typescript if there is object inside object

Tags: json, angular, typescript

i have a json data like   :

```
{"extra":"main menu",
"menu":[
{"id":1,"name":"Menu 1"}
,{"id":2,"name":"Menu 2"}
,{"id":3,"name":"Menu 3"}
,{"id":4,"name":"Menu 4"}
,{"id":5,"name":"Menu 5"}
,{"id":6,"name":"Menu 6",
 "menu":[
         {"id":7,"name":"Menu 7.1"},
         {"id":8,"name":"Menu 7.2"},
         {"id":9,"name":"Menu 7.3"}
]},
{"id":10,"name":"Menu 8  "},
{"id":12,"name":"Menu 9 "},

}
```

i have a class menu like that :

```
export class Menu {
constructor(public id?: number , public name?: string ){}
}
```

and a  parser like :

```
export class ParserMenu {

constuctor(public module?: string , public menu?: Menu[])
}
```

i can get data and parse it correctly but the problem is when i have a menu inside a menu , i don't know how to parse this data so , what is the solution to solve that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you use interfaces instead of classes, I see no need for using a class here ;) So it would look like this:

```
export interface Menu {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  menu?: Menu[]
}
```

Then you just simply cast your JSON to this interface when retrieving data (I assume it's coming from backend) by extracting the data from `menu`:

Service:

```
getData(): Observable<Menu[]>{
  return this.http.get('theUrl')
    .map(res => res.json().menu)
}
```

and in component:

```
menues: Menu[];

this.service.getData()
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.menues = data;       
  })
```

Now you have data of type `Menu`. Worth mentioning is, that interfaces do not exist during runtime, as there is no interfaces in JS. Interfaces are more of a help for the programmer and IDE. IDE can warn you during compile time if you are trying to do something wrong, like assigning wrong type for properties.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse()` will not instantiate any of your classes. So you'd better use interfaces instead of classes to model the structure of your JSON.

But if you have a menu inside a menu, then... that menu will be inside the menu in the object created by `JSON.parse()`, too. You access it using `result.menu[5].menu`.

And you thus need a `menu?` attribute, of type `Array<Menu>`, inside `Menu`.

Comment: can you give me some code example how to parse it completely ?

Comment: JSON.parse(jsonString) does parse it completely. Not sure what you're asking.